# How do i make sure that Electron express app is only accessible from inside electron window

Tags: javascript, express, electron

I new to express, so i made this small demo app, to test it out:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const express = require('express');
const ex_app = express();


// express
// ----------------------------------------
const ex_port = 5000;

ex_app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
ex_app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');

ex_app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index', {title: 'Root', message: 'root page loaded'});
});

ex_app.listen(ex_port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${ex_port}!`);
});
// ----------------------------------------

// electron
// ----------------------------------------
app.once('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width:           500,
    height:          400,
    titleBarStyle:   'hiddenInset',
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    show:            false
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5000/');

  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.focus();
    mainWindow.maximize();
  });
});
// ----------------------------------------
```

But i noticed that the express app is also accessible in browser, by entering `http://localhost:5000`, so i wanted to know, is it possible to automatically disable anyone accessing it from outside electron window?

I had an idea to pass uniq token to electron window, similarly to this:

```
let token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:5000/?token=${token}`);
```

and then just send it with all requests and change it every time, but that seems like hassle, and one would think, there should be a better solution, to handles this automatically..

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your token to cookie/user agent. For example:

```
ex_app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.get('User-Agent').endsWith(token)) {
    return next();
  }

  res.end()
});
...
mainWindow.webContents.setUserAgent(mainWindow.webContents.getUserAgent() + token);
```